# How does this old zoom and pan d3js code translate to d3js.v7?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, graph, deprecated

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the SVG object to the body of the page
var SVG = d3.select("#dataviz_axisZoom")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/iris.csv", function(data) {

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([4, 8])
    .range([ 0, width ]);
  var xAxis = SVG.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 9])
    .range([ height, 0]);
  var yAxis = SVG.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Add a clipPath: everything out of this area won't be drawn.
  var clip = SVG.append("defs").append("SVG:clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("SVG:rect")
      .attr("width", width )
      .attr("height", height )
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);

  // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
  var scatter = SVG.append('g')
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

  // Add circles
  scatter
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Sepal_Length); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.Petal_Length); } )
      .attr("r", 8)
      .style("fill", "#61a3a9")
      .style("opacity", 0.5)

  // Set the zoom and Pan features: how much you can zoom, on which part, and what to do when there is a zoom
  var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([.5, 20])  // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on("zoom", updateChart);

  // This add an invisible rect on top of the chart area. This rect can recover pointer events: necessary to understand when the user zoom
  SVG.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
      .call(zoom);
  // now the user can zoom and it will trigger the function called updateChart

  // A function that updates the chart when the user zoom and thus new boundaries are available
  function updateChart() {

    // recover the new scale
    var newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
    var newY = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y);

    // update axes with these new boundaries
    xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX))
    yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY))

    // update circle position
    scatter
      .selectAll("circle")
      .attr('cx', function(d) {return newX(d.Sepal_Length)})
      .attr('cy', function(d) {return newY(d.Petal_Length)});
  }

})
```

I tried using this code but I keep getting errors saying that the d3.event.transform function (in the updateChat() function) doesn't work anymore and is deprecated in the new versions of d3js. How do I write this code in the latest version of d3.js. I'm trying to figure out how to use the zoom function in d3js to change the scale of the axis as well as the content rather than just the content like most online guides on the d3js zoom function cover.

Answer (score 1):

Add an argument to the `updateChart` function and use the argument instead of `d3.event.transform`. I named the paramter `zoomEvent`, so the result is:

```js
var newX = zoomEvent.transform.rescaleX(x);
var newY = zoomEvent.transform.rescaleY(y);
```

The data does not seem to be displaying in the code you provided, but here is complete code with working axis zooming. You can try it on https://codepen.io/pen/.

```js
import * as d3 from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3@7.8.4";

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the SVG object to the body of the page
var SVG = d3
  .select("#dataviz_axisZoom")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Add X axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([4, 8]).range([0, width]);
var xAxis = SVG.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .attr("id", "xAxis")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 9]).range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = SVG.append("g").attr("id", "yAxis").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Add a clipPath: everything out of this area won't be drawn.
var clip = SVG.append("defs")
  .append("SVG:clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("SVG:rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0);

// Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
var scatter = SVG.append("g").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

//Read the data
d3.csv(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/iris.csv",
  function (data) {
    // Add circles
    scatter
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return x(d.Sepal_Length);
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return y(d.Petal_Length);
      })
      .attr("r", 8)
      .style("fill", "#61a3a9")
      .style("opacity", 0.5);

    // Set the zoom and Pan features: how much you can zoom, on which part, and what to do when there is a zoom
    var zoom = d3
      .zoom()
      .scaleExtent([0.5, 20]) // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
      .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height]
      ])
      .on("zoom", updateChart);

    // This add an invisible rect on top of the chart area. This rect can recover pointer events: necessary to understand when the user zoom
    SVG.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);
    // now the user can zoom and it will trigger the function called updateChart

    // A function that updates the chart when the user zoom and thus new boundaries are available
    function updateChart(zoomEvent) {
      // recover the new scale
      var newX = zoomEvent.transform.rescaleX(x);
      var newY = zoomEvent.transform.rescaleY(y);

      // update axes with these new boundaries
      xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX));
      yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY));

      // update circle position
      scatter
        .selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
          return newX(d.Sepal_Length);
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
          return newY(d.Petal_Length);
        });
    }
  }
);
```